# Android: Trying to have diffrent layouts for difrrent screen sizes

Tags: android

I'm trying to have different screen layouts for different screen size.  Pre in this group a person talked about having the layouts in different folders, and android will choose the right one.

Right now the same layout always gets chosen.  I have a small Vergin Andorid smart phone and a acer tablet.  In the android smart phone the buttons take up the width of the sceren and the layout from layout-mdpi is being loaded.

On my tablet the file is being loaded from folder layout-mdpi and the buttons only take up half the width of the screen.

Currently I have the following folders:

```
layout
layout-hdpi
layout-ldpi
layout-mdpi
layout-xhdpi.
```

And the layout is the same except I change the text for Vol to say vol1, vol2, vol3, vol4 so I know what folder the file is coming from.

Comment: Google "Android Screen Size" and click on the very first hit. You're confusing screen density with size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split my layout folders by density pixel values. So for example on large tablet screens I would use "layout-sw720dp" and on medium tablets I would use "layout-sw600dp".  If you need different layout structures for portrait and landscape then you could for example add a folder for "layout-sw720dp-land" and "layout-sw720dp-port"

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find answer. I hope this help.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html